# Passing an integer from a public class to a form in VB6

Tags: vb.net

I'm implementing a loading bar in a program to show completion progress when my user completes questions in a database. I'm trying to keep an active value for the loading bar so that when someone completes a question, the loading bar will fill up a little more.

I'm trying to allow for values from across the system to use and change the value for the percentage bar, I'm using a public class to hold all the values for calculating the percentage.

"The type initializer for 'WindowsApplication1.Percentage' threw an exception." is the only error message that I receive.

When I try to load the form containing the loading bar, the system crashes. Could someone please provide some information on what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank You.

```
Private Sub HomeScreenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles HomeScreenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    HomeScreen.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub LogOffToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LogOffToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Start_Screen.Show()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub SFLink_LinkClicked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles SFLink.LinkClicked

End Sub

Private Sub NumbersMenu_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ProgressBar1.Value = Percentage.Percentage

End Sub
End Class

Public Class Percentage
Public Shared Percentage As Integer = (QuestionCompletion / QuestionCount) * 100
Public Shared QuestionCompletion As Integer = 5
Public Shared QuestionCount As Integer = 100
'The values for QuestionCompletion and QuestionCount are here for testing at the moment
End Class
```

Comment: Look at the InnerException.  It will tell you that you are dividing by zero, QuestionCount is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making Percentage a readonly property

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Percentage 
        Get
            Return (QuestionCompletion / QuestionCount) * 100
        End Get
End Property
```

Comment: @IrahMeakin-Wong upvote and marka s correct please :)